# I am facing a problems.I have a csv file contains only one feature called address..i need to find the place name using NLP.How can i do it?

Tags: nlp

I am facing a problems.I have a csv file contains only one feature called address..i need to find the place name using NLP.How can i do it?

I am writting you to get some help or getting some ideas to solve the problem.You can can give some suggestion